# Splatoon model resource ALB s not working

Tags: modeling, transparency

So for the past few days I've been working on a splatoon model, the first problem I ran into was the eyelid ALB s which has to be connected to the alpha channel, this however comes out black when in the tutorial I was watching it came out fully white, is there any fix to this, EX changing the color of the actual ALB_s to the white I want or is the inkling model from models resource just not viable with blender 3.1 now? the tutorial i was watching is the second part to a three part series made by velepexon, please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what means ALB?